# Ansible pre-check before run playbook

Tags: ansible

Is it possible to add a condition before to run a playbook which check if there is a title, a description, the environment and the versions on the playbook ?

For example my test.yml playbook:

```
---
#Apache servers  
#Linux  
#Ubuntu  
#version 2.1.1  
#Testing for secure the webserver

  task:
    xxxxxx
    xxxxxx
```

And I would like to check if all the comment before are present before to run this task !

I tried to test this solution :

```
name: run Apachetest playbook
include: test.yml
    when: "{{ lookup('file', 'test.yml').split('\n')[1] == '#Apache servers' }}"
```

But still not working...

BS

Comment: basically ansible always tries to reach a desired states. Probably you don't need all these checks e.g.  apache running. The test.yml could only be a list of when than debug message. Probably you want to share your test.yml ?

Comment: Yes indeed, the main goal is related to compliance check ...

Answer (score 0):

Comments are, well, comments. They do not impact the execution and are just ignored. So there is no way, and actually no real reason, to check if comments are present or not. You would need to implement that yourself.

To check playbooks, roles, etc. there is [ansible-lint](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-lint) which will verify the syntax and some best practices (e.g. if you use a `command` or `shell` for something there is a module for) but this does not verify comments (again, checking for comments does not make sense from a execution perspective, as they are ignored).

You want some information to be present in your playbook, that is what I understand. If I was you, I would either create a `git` hook, that verifies if the information is present before letting you push that code to your repository or establish a proper review-process, where the reviewer only accepts a merge/pull request, if the information is present.

Otherwise, here is the code, that will do what you are trying to do:

```yaml
---
#Apache server
- hosts: all
  tasks:    
  - name: set fact
    set_fact:
      pb: "{{ lookup('file', 'test.yml').split('\n')[1] }}"
  - name: check if we found it
    debug:
      msg: 'found'
    when: "'#Apache server' in pb"
```

Comment: We are using already lint for the syntax which is a good indeed !
I will try this during my shift tonight !
Thanks

Comment: is that possible to include all the other comment ? Like if the first comment is on the playbook and the second and the third and the fourth etc.
I have tried to add them on the When but seems to be stuck

Comment: You need to replicate both task for each line. The first task extracts the `n`th line and the second one checks if the given string is in there.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the apache role for apache installed like that

```
---
- hosts: apache
  sudo: yes
  tasks:
    - name: install apache2
      apt: name=apache2 update_cache=yes state=latest
```

have a look here [how-to-install-apache-on-ansible](https://www.scaleway.com/en/docs/how-to-install-apache-on-ansible/)

Comment: This will install the latest version of the apache webserver, but not check if there is a comment in the playbook (which is what OP asked for).

Comment: ok than this is just good if he wants to make sure it is installed not that to report if it is installed. you are right. But than ansible is probaly wrong for compliance in that direction